# libGDX/roboVM: How to fix "Native Library libhfscompressor.dylib already loaded in another classloader"?

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx, robovm

I'm using roboVM (1.0.0) with libGDX (1.5.5) in Android Studio (1.1.0) and face the problem that execution on an iOS device works only after deleting the gradle directory (~/.gradle). Without prior deletion of ~/.gradle, execution fails with the following error message:

> [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library ~/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/1.0.0/unpacked/robovm-1.0.0/bin/libhfscompressor.dylib already loaded in another classloader

Do you have any ideas what might cause this problem or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid, I haven't found a fix or workaround for this one yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fine folks at badlogic games posted a solution here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/867

It comes down to disabling the Gradle build deamon by setting `org.gradle.daemon=false` in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call ./gradlew --stop then run you're ios:launchiOSSimulator / device for it too work.